# How to check my Facebook AccessToken? How to renew it? (.NET Desktop Application)

Tags: facebook

I've created a Facebook .NET Desktop Application. On the first run, the application opens a second window with a Web Browser directed to the authorization page for my application with the required permissions from the user.

If the user authorizes my app, Facebook is redirecting me to the static login_success.html and appends the AccessToken to the Hash (#) part of the Url of the browser rendered in my second .NET Application window.

I hand that AccessToken to my main application window and do my requests to the graph api on behalf of the respective user.

That's fine, and working so far!

But, how can I

- check if the AccessToken I've stored is still valid and how
- can I renew an expired AccessToken without bugging the user with the second browser window (of course assuming the user hasn't revoked the authorization for my app) and how
- can I recognize that the user has revoked the authorization?

Answer (score 2):

- check if the AccessToken I've stored is still valid?

Try and use the token against the Graph, and if it give you an error (Something like OAuthException or OAuthError), it's not valid, else it still is.

- Can I renew an expired AccessToken without bugging the user with the second browser?

No that I know of.  But, AccessTokens (with the Offline Access permission) don't expire.  I've received an AccessToken for one of my apps almost 2 years ago and it hasn't changed or expired, so I think you should be good. They might become invalid if your App Secret changes or if the user changes their password (I'm pretty sure on that last one, but not 100%)

- Can I recognize that the user has revoked the authorization?

Yes, if you query the Graph with an AccessToken that is not authorized for that function, it will give you an OAuthException.  Just check for exceptions after you receive Graph data and it will let you know, for the most part, why you weren't able to receive Facebook data.

Comment: No way to renew the access-token without user-interaction? What if his application for some reason misses the redirect after authorization (with the code/token in the uri)? Is it gone forever (although the user accepted the auth-request)?

Comment: That is different.  The access-token is tied to a session.  The application authorization is tied to the actual fb user.  By "bugging" the user, I mean they have to log in with their username & password, not re-authorize the app.  And if the user has the "Keep me logged into FB" checked (giving them the magical FB cookie) the OAuth session will be renewed w/o any interaction from the user.  A new AccessToken is generated and passed back to your application

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if your Access Token expires you have to get the user to go through Facebook to get a new Access Token.  An offline_access token does not ever expire due to time, like joe_coolish pointed out, but it does expire if the user changes their password.  So your program needs recognize when a user's access token is invalid and get the user "refresh it" by going through the oauth endpoint.

Recognizing that the user's token is invalid is the same process as recognizing that the user has revoked authorization for your application.  Whenever you make a graph request with an invalid access token, Facebook will give you an OAuthException saying that you don't have access.